# access-control-allow-headers: * is being ignored

Tags: cors, request-headers, response-headers, http-options-method

Although the OPTIONS returns `*` for Allow-Headers I'm getting the following CORS response.

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at `'https://example1.com'` from origin `'https://example2.net'` has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field x-requested-with is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

While the OPTION request looks like this:

```
Request Method: OPTIONS
Status Code: 204
```

Request headers:

```
Access-Control-Request-Headers: x-requested-with
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.121 Safari/537.36
```

Response headers:

```
access-control-allow-credentials: true
access-control-allow-headers: *
access-control-allow-methods: GET,POST
access-control-max-age: 86400
content-length: 0
content-type: text/plain charset=UTF-8
date: Wed, 12 Jun 2019 05:03:06 GMT
status: 204
```

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Headers#Compatibility_notes

Comment: @sideshowbarker - This answer is from 2013, the current browser should support the wild card already.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue with Firefox and IE but not in chrome. Instead of setting the access-control-allow-headers: * add a comma separated list of the headers allowed like this **Authorization,Content-Type,X-Requested-With,accept,Origin,Access-Control-Request-Method,Access-Control-Request-Headers** it worked for me through a filter